# Performance comparison of AngularJS "watch"-es vs "emit/on"s with 3rd party Libraries (like OpenLayers)

Tags: performance, angularjs, event-handling, angularjs-directive, openlayers

We are in the process of re-engineering the client-side of a GIS application that uses [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) (for map manipulations) from jQuery into AngularJS. In the case of event sharing between AngularJS and OpenLayers(OL), we have got the following 2 approaches so far (Two things : An OL directive is being created to wrap the OL activities; and A structured data-model entity is maintained for data binding of the entire client-side in which all the map related data can also be hold).

1. Observer pattern implementation: Having a shared event-bus-system with $emit/on-s so, both Angular and OL components allow to deal with each other.
2. Treating the Data-Model as the shared medium : To hold the latest state of the application, So the event sharing of each framework will be as follows,

   - OL -> AngularJS event communication : whenever an OL event occurs it get triggered within OL directive and update the relevant part of the data-model which is bound to the Angular UI to show the updates real time (Ex : Map is clicked, the current location is shown in a side-panel)
   - AngularJS -> OL event communication : use watches inside the OL directive on the relevant parts of the data-model so the OL map responds for the UI events in Angular JS (Ex : Click the layer list of the side panel on Angular JS, then the OL map shows the layer clicked)

**Notes :**
- This is an enterprise SPA which will have many cross component activities done by the user logged in simultaneously. So, no of concurrent events triggered will be comparatively higher.
- There will be more cases of dynamic content manipulation between AngularJS and OL map (Ex : At the use login, it will load all the maps and layers of the user and show them in the map component, etc)

**Considerations :** 
Main considerations (within the context of the question) are,
- Performance of the application specially on mobile optimized environment (Android, iOS) on event handling/sharing
- Maintainability : To be able to manage the app for future enhancements with no additional overhead on event management

**Question :** 
What would be the better and optimum solution for the question out of (1) and (2) above or unseen (3)?

PS : Please kindly do let me know if I should provide any more info to complete the whole picture of the question if I haven't done it.

**Update :**
- The question is basically the decision of using "watch"-es or "emit/on"-s that gives the best performance of a system having many (I am sorry that I dont have an exact figure for this, say for ex < 100)  concurrent event firings.

Thanks in advance.
Dhammika

Comment: It's very hard to say anything about performance without knowing a lot more of the size of the application, and even if I did I am still not sure what exactly it is you're asking about. That being said, having a large amount of `$watch`es on a page might lead to performance issues. If I recall correctly this talk from JSConfEU compares data-binding perfomance in different SPA frameworks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVjpwia1YN4, while it might not answer whatever it is you're asking it might give some context.

Comment: Also note that the Angular team plans to start using `Object.observe` once ES6 is finalized. This will change the playing field, but will obviously only benefit browsers that supports ES6.

Comment: Also, maybe take a look at this talk from NGConf about Angular performance: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyYpHIOrk_Y. Sorry for just dumping links on you but I really feel that it's hard to say anything specific without knowing a lot more about the actual app.

Comment: Thanks for the replies @ivarni, The question is basically the decision of using "watch"-es or "emit/on"-s that gives the best performance of a system having many (I am sorry that I dont have an exact figure for this, say for ex < 100)  concurrent event firings.